# "This is a favorite question" tooltip when not favorite

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks, tooltips

When viewing a question, when I hover over the star icon (under the voting module) the tooltip says I've made it a favorite when I haven't yet.

Comment: I find it ambiguous too. The _click again to undo_ might be misunderstood as if the system things you have already faved and want to undo it now. But it is just stating the possibility that you can undo it by clicking again.

Comment: @Oded: Seems like it would be simple enough to push a conditional tooltip to the page.  Something like "Click here to put this question in your 'favorites' list", or "You have favorited this question (click to undo)."

Comment: @Oded oddly enough, looks like this was changed at some point without any announcement, now the tooltip says "Click to mark as favorite question" which is exactly the fix OP here wanted. Can you please mark as completed, possibly adding answer telling when this was done? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean it says "This is a favorite question (click again to undo)"? The tooltip is telling you what will happen if you click. Just like if you haven't down-voted a question yet, the tooltip tells you you already think the question is not useful.

In other words, the tooltip is telling you what performing the action subsequently means, not what you may have done with that entity in the past.

Comment: I see. Strange that it says "click again".

Comment: Because you will favorite then un-favorite the question if you click twice. Don't see how this is strange, it's just describing two possible outcomes if you take *any* action on the entity in question.

Comment: It seems strange because the method of tooltip captioning is inconsistent. For example, the check mark icon next to this answer has tooltip "click to set ... click again to toggle", which makes sense (it provides clear instructions, rather than making a present-tense statement about the state of the answer after you click it). It would be weird if the checkmark button's tooltip stated "This is the selected answer" before clicking. The tooltips for the up/down vote are fine, but the 'favorite' button's instruction would be more clear with text that is more descriptive of that button's action.

Comment: I agree it's inconsistent in some cases. So maybe you should re-word your question as a feature request to make the tense more consistent. But I wouldn't bet on it getting highly up-voted as there are far more important things for the devs to work on IMHO. Wording on tooltips that have been that way for ages and I don't think have ever caused anyone a problem before is not really a bug or strange imho.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you think the tooltips for up/down vote are fine but the tooltip for favorite is not. They are stated the exact same way (the state of the entity once you've clicked, not before) with the same consequence as a suffix.

Comment: The difference with the up/down buttons is that their meanings are pretty intuitive even without the tooltip. Most users probably already know what those buttons are going to do before hovering. Also, the fact that there are two opposing buttons give the user an opportunity to clarify the meaning of the tooltip by hovering over the opposing one. The star icon has a less intuitive meaning.

Comment: <shrug> ok.....

Comment: I agree with bevanb, it's not all that important but I do find it confusing - a little more clarity couldn't hurt imo.

Answer (score 2):

That text is a little ambiguous with its text:

> This is a favorite question (click again to undo)

since the phrase "click again to undo" seems to say that you have already done something.  When you hover over an answer upvote it hints:

> This answer is useful

and then *after* it is clicked it says:

> This answer is useful (click again to undo)

similarly for the question upvote, question downvote and answer downvote tooltips.

We should probably reword the favorite question tooltip to something like:

> This is a favorite question

and *after* it is clicked:

> This is a favorite question (click again to undo)

Comment: Here is [another answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266648/1429387) stating the same.

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The tooltip for an unfavorited question has been changed to read "*Click to mark as favorite question (click again to undo)*".

[image: Tooltip on unfavorited question]

Comment: Where can I find a question that I marked as a favorite question? Is there an easy way I can search for it? And does pressing the star button gives any reputations for the person that asked the question?