# Data Explorer shows "This is a favorite query" for unfavorited queries

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, bookmarks, tooltips

The hover text for the Favorite Query star on [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/330763/find-all-my-unaccepted-question-network-wide) displays the hover text "*This is a favorite query (click again to undo)*".

[image: Hover text - Logged in & favorited]

This hover text shows the same message even if the query hasn't been favorited, or if the user is logged out:

[image: Hover text - Logged out]

The tooltip for an unfavorited question should read "*Click to mark as favorite question (click again to undo)*", similar to its appearance on Meta Stack Exchange.

[image: MSE - Favorite text]

Comment: Would it be possible to fix this with a single text that still makes sense for each state? If so, what would that text be?

Comment: @rene see how it works here, and on all SE sites. That's what OP is after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As can be deducted from ["This is a favorite question" tooltip when not favorite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143350/this-is-a-favorite-question-tooltip-when-not-favorite), this is how it was in Stack Overflow as well for long time and changed silently at some point, without any notice.

Since SEDE took its UX from SO, it's natural they copied this behavior as well.

Now that it's changed across Stack Exchange, someone can also change it in SEDE source code and submit pull request (it's open source), and it will be merged to production at some point.

**Update**: such pull request [has indeed been submitted](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/83) by [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) in July 6<sup>th</sup> 2017, and merged with production branch in July 25<sup>th</sup>.

Comment: The text *Click to mark as favorite question (click again to undo)* doesn't make sense if you have a text for the alternate state. Better would be *Click to mark as favorite question*

Comment: @rene yes, that's how they changed in across SE sites. But SEDE is open source, so someone has to change it manually in there.